# How do I use a single character from variable type char** in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to work with only the first character of a string, that is within `argv[]`. I was thinking something like `argv[1[2]]`, but that doesn't work or make much sense.

Comment: Use `argv[1][2]` to access the third character in the second string of `argv`.  Or use `argv[0][0]` to access the first character of the first string — which is the name of the program if you have `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 1):

As with a lot of things in C, you de-reference the pointer, and the easiest way is by treating it as an array:

```
char** arguments = argv;
char* first_argument = argv[0];
char first_letter = argv[0][0];
```

This is also equivalent to:

```
char first_letter = first_argument[0];
```

And you can go in reverse by assigning the address of something to a pointer:

```
char* argument = &first_letter;
```

Your attempt is this:

```
argv[1[2]]
```

Which implies there's some value like this:

```
int i = 1[2];
argv[i];
```

Where `1[2]` is not something C can deal with.